# Which program should I use if I want to draw/sketch to a .pdf files?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

It would be nice to have a program which I can use to do some drawing/sketching in a .pdf document and I can also scroll up or down.

Like this:

[image]

(Edited with GIMP)

It is not necessary to save the documents with the sketch.

Is there any program that can do these?

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/167274/how-can-i-edit-a-picture-into-an-existing-pdf-file

Answer (score -1):

While there is a lot of way to import and then modify a PDF under Ubuntu, you could try **Master PDF Editor** that provide a Linux version and even a deb version for Ubuntu.

[Website here](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/#get) and direct [DEB download link here](http://get.code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor-4.3.10_qt5.amd64.deb).

> **Note**: this is not an Open Source software and they provides commercial version with more advanced editing option. Also, I'm not affiliated with this company and I tried the software before posting here.