# Put signature onto pdf file

Tags: gui, pdf, image-processing

I have two files: A pdf file and a png file with my signature.

Now I want to put the png image file onto the pdf on a particular place.

Which GUI tool could help me here?

Comment: Similar question https://askubuntu.com/questions/167274/how-can-i-edit-a-picture-into-an-existing-pdf-file ?

Comment: Wow, fast answer. And: Perfect! The tool `xournal` can annotate pdf files